# Wordpress: Tribe Events list feed or json

Tags: json, wordpress, feed

I'm running a Wordpress site with [Event Calendar plugin by Modern Tribe](http://tri.be/shop/wordpress-events-calendar/).

I wonder how I can have a feed or json of all my events to be processed by another application (i.e. a mobile app). In the docs, I found out I can add **/feed** at my calendar's url to get the feed xml, but it's not retrieving important information such as palce and time of the event.

Has anyone any suggestion? My second choice is to build an extra php file for processing raw queries in the db.

Thanks

Comment: Did you try a JSON API plugin?

Comment: Yes, I already use the JSON API plugin. It doesn't work both in implicit or explicit way.